# Firebase Unity: OrderByChild().StartAt().EndAt() returns nothing

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

This query returns nothing every time. What am I missing? Thank you!

Query:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("submissions").
OrderByChild("Time").StartAt(100000000).EndAt(999999999).LimitToFirst(10);
```

Data structure:

```
{
    "submissions": {
        "key1": {
            "Time": 100000001
        },
        "key2": {
            "Time": 100000005
        }
    }
}
```

Call:

```
query.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of the actual JSON at `submissions` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).